# Is there a way to detect a string and then remove a subset of it in R?

Tags: r

I have a very large dataset from which, I want to detect a specific string, somewhere in the whole review and then remove white spaces from it. Here's an example:

A string that contains **Happy Meal** should be replaced by **HappyMeal**
or
A string consisting of **cheeseburger meal** should be replaced by **cheeseburgermeal**

Here are all methods that I have tried:

1.

```
data %>% pull(body) %>%
  str_replace_all(c("happy meal" = "happymeal", "chicken nuggets meal" = "chickennuggetsmeal",
                  "chicken legend meal" = "chickenlegendmeal",
                  "double cheeseburger meal" = "doublecheeseburgermeal"))
```

The code above executes without error so I have no output to share for this one but when I check the dataset the changes still do not exist.
*(Edit) after assigning it, I get one long string of 5000000 characters which is not what I want, I want individual comments within the body to remain separated.*

2.

```
 str_remove(str_detect(("happy meal|chicken nuggets meal|chicken legend meal|double cheeseburger meal")), " ")
```

OUTPUT

> ```
> Error in str_remove(., str_detect(("happy meal|chicken nuggets
> meal|chicken legend meal|double cheeseburger meal")),  :   
> unused argument (" ")
> ```

3. 

```
data$body <- str_remove(str_detect(data$body,
 ("happy meal|chicken nuggets meal|chicken legend meal|double cheeseburger meal")), " ")
```

This output also executes but returns all values in body as Booleans, which I am aware, is because `string _detect()` returns a boolean. Another way I have tried is by assigning a new variable to the whole body string, which just returns one extremely long character string. I might be making some very silly mistakes, however, I can't seem to figure out what mistake am making in obtaining strings without spaces so any help is appreciated!

Comment: In your example 1 you're not modifying your dataset because you're not making any assignment.

Comment: Do you want to do anything else than removing the space? Becuase in your examples that is what you do. So why doesn't a simple `gsub("\\s", "", .)` work?

Comment: @Limey when I assign it I get one long character string, I'll edit my question to show that now

Comment: @Annet because each review consists of a long character string and I dont want to eliminate all the spaces just the ones which appear between food objects. Furthermore, If it was just meal, I would use regex, but I also need to elminate the spaces between **Double** and **cheeseburger** or **chicken** and **legend**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Replace all Whitespace

If you want to remove whitespace from all entries in the column you can use

```
# Load dplyr for `mutate()` and `%>%`
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(body = gsub(" ", "", body))
```

## Replace Based on String Length

If you only want to apply the above when the entries in `body` are greater than a certain number of characters, say, 20, then you can do so as follows:

```
data %>%
  mutate(body = ifelse(nchar(body > 20), gsub(" ", "", body), body))
```

## Replace Only Some Whitespace

Finally, if you only want to replace *some* whitespace in *some* strings, you can use `stringr::str_replace_all()` (as you suggested). This will also replace *substrings*, so e.g. "Bought a Happy meal and two strawberry milkshakes" will become "Bought a Happymeal and two strawberry milkshakes".

```
replace_vals <- c("happy meal", "chicken nuggets meal", "chicken legend meal",
                  "double cheeseburger meal")

data %>%
  mutate(body = stringr::str_replace_all(
    string = body,
    # Values to replace
    pattern = replace_vals,
    # For replacements we can just remove the spaces from `replace_vals`
    replacement = gsub(" ", "", replace_vals)
  ))
```

## Saving the result

Note, to permanently apply any of these changes to your `data` you will need to reassign the result. E.g. `data <- data %>% # ...code that changes stuff`

Comment: @BluVoxeThanks! but in **replace certain values** I want values in replace_vals to be searched for in body. All values in body aren't restricted to just "happy meal" or "chicken nuggets meal". The comments are of the kind, "Bought a Happy meal and two strawberry milkshakes."

Comment: Ah I understand! Updating my answer now.

Comment: Just tried this, however I get the error ```longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length```. By the way, I ultimately just end up using several different ```str_replace_all``` for every individual phrase, but I am surprised that there isn't a more elecgant way to do this

Comment: Ah yeah, I forgot about that! Actually this should just be a `warning` which, while annoying, shouldn't actually stop your code running. You can wrap the call to `str_replace_all()` with `suppressWarnings()` if it's causing issues, which I think should finally be what you're after?

Comment: Ah ye just checked, clever, I wasn't aware that gsub() could be put in replacement; it works thank youu!!